# Graphql query: how to create a query that returns different fields between items

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

My query is find a company in the database, returns some basic information, and the financials information over the years. The result looks like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "company": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test company",
      "companyType": "NH",
      "financials": [
        {
          "year": 2018,
          "netRevenue": 0,
          "costOfSales": 0,
          "grossProfit": 0,
          "financialIncome": 0,
          "financialExpenses": 0,
          "resultOfOtherActivities": 0
        },
        {
          "year": 2017,
          "netRevenue": 0,
          "costOfSales": 0,
          "grossProfit": 0,
          "financialIncome": 0,
          "financialExpenses": 0,
          "resultOfOtherActivities": 0
        },
        {
          "year": 2016,
          "netRevenue": 0,
          "costOfSales": 0,
          "grossProfit": 0,
          "financialIncome": 0,
          "financialExpenses": 0,
          "resultOfOtherActivities": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Very simple to write the query:

```
{
  company {
    id
    name
    companyType
    financials {
      year
      netRevenue
      costOfSales
      grossProfit
      financialIncome
      financialExpenses
      resultOfOtherActivities
    }
  }
}
```

But my case is not so simple. I need a query just to retrieve some of the fields for each year. The result looks like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "company": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test company",
      "companyType": "NH",
      "financials": [
        {
          "year": 2018,
          "netRevenue": 0
        },
        {
          "year": 2017,
          "grossProfit": 0,
          "financialIncome": 0,
          "financialExpenses": 0
        },
        {
          "year": 2016,
          "resultOfOtherActivities": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way that a query can achieve such a result?

Comment: I don't think you can do exactly what you're looking for. You could add a directive (https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives) for the fields that you conditionally want, but then you'd have to call the query separately for the different years, passing in different booleans.

Comment: @JasonDown The cost of repeating the query will be expensive

Comment: Yes it would. But I don't think there is a way to do what you want any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to write a query like that.

All the items returned in a particular list will have the same selection set. The only exception is when you're requesting a field with a union or interface type -- then you can use inline fragments to specify a selection set for each possible type.

As already suggested in the comments, the only possible workaround is to utilize aliases. Assuming your schema allows you to filter the `financials` field by year, you'd do something like this:

```
{
  company {
    id
    name
    companyType
    financials2007: financials(year: 2007) {
      ...FinancialsFields
    }
    financials2008: financials(year: 2008) {
      ...FinancialsFields
    }
    financials2009: financials(year: 2009) {
      ...FinancialsFields
    }
  }
}

fragment FinancialsFields on Financials {
  year
  netRevenue
  costOfSales
  grossProfit
  financialIncome
  financialExpenses
  resultOfOtherActivities
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I can use alias in my case. Thank you very much :D